Generic objects characterized by objects in the ground model
Kibedi showed, in his doctoral thesis, Maximal saturated linear orders (Lemma 4.3.1), the equivalence of existence between a ccc poset that adds a new $\omega_1$-gap in a linear order in the ground model and a Suslin tree in the ground model.
I want to call this new gap by a ccc-generic $\omega_1$-gap.
I am interested in this result and would like to know if other examples exist: a ccc-generic object (or, for any property $\Phi$ of forcings, $\Phi$-generic object) is equivalent to an object in the ground model.
